# How do I grep for a greater than symbol?

Tags: linux, grep, special-characters

I am trying to grep for a php function call

`grep -Ri '->someFunction' .`

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `grepping` in `.`, `grep` all files.  `grep '->someFunction' *.*`

Comment: I updated my question to reflect my actual use of using the `-Ri` flags

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's not the quotes : try this :

```
grep -Ri -- '->someFunction' .
```

the `--` part stands for *end of options* ;  it's a shell trick.

Comment: Thank you! it totally worked! `grep -Ri -- '->someFunction' .`

Comment: If you're on an old system you have to say '`grep -e`' instead of '`grep --`'.  However, greps that old probably don't support `-R`.

Comment: Also, it would be better to describe `--` as "end of *options*", not "end of *arguments*".  You have got arguments after the `--`, it's just that a leading `-` is no longer special.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where "it's not working" isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

In your case, the error message you got was

```
 grep: invalid option -- >
```

That is your clue to see that `->someFunction` is being seen as a command-line switch.

I also suggest that you may want to look at [ack](http://betterthangrep.com), which is meant for this sort of source code searching.  In your case, you would do:

```
ack -i -- '->someFunction'
```